# outlook powershell replied email property

Tags: c#, vba, powershell, outlook

Hi I am creating a powershell script to read e-mail from outlook on which i have replied. can someone help me to find out the property in the variable.
all emails are in $monitor variable.

```
Add-type -assembly “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook” | out-null

$olFolders = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders” -as [type]

$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application

$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)

$folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox)

$Monitor  = $folder.Folders.Item("Test")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/15323686/478656 and comments at https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/forward-messages-not-replied/ it looks like you want

```
$Email.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003")
```

Which is the property for `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED`, and the output is either 0 (not replied), 102 ('Reply') or 103 ('Reply All').

So maybe

```
$LastVerb = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003"
$Monitor.Items | Where-Object { $_.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty($LastVerb) -gt 0 }
```